# How to find out the query being sent into SQLite in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, logcat

My question is concerned with SQLite database in Android.

When I use a statement like

```
cursor c = databaseHelper.rawQuery("SELECT " +user_id+" from "+DATABASE_TABLE,new String [] {});
```

How can I find out the query being sent to the database ?
Is there any way to print the query in Logcat ?

Comment: I dont think there is way other than you manually logging it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While others have mentioned manually logging the query before calling `databaseHelper.rawQuery` the big problem with that approach is that modifications are required at call-site, adding the logging statements everywhere the method is called.

I have not worked on Android but for the exact same issue of logging queries I have used `AspectJ` with great success. A quick search and glance at [android-aspectj](http://code.google.com/p/android-aspectj/) suggests the combination works.

**Overall, this seems to be prime cross-cutting usecase and `AspectJ` would be the best approach.**

Answer (score 1):

You can logcat it if you want so.
Log.d("Query", "youQuery");

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
String query = "SELECT " +user_id+" from "+DATABASE_TABLE;
Log.d("SQL_QUERY", query);
cursor c = databaseHelper.rawQuery(query,new String [] {});
```

Sure, it is better to extend class and override methods.

Answer (score 0):

An aspect is definitely the way to go. But, for this particular use-case, I'd do something a little bit more custom, such as extending your `ContentProvider` implementation and then doing all the logging in your subclass.

In the end, this is just an interceptor, but it's ugly because you can't use a decorator with composition, since your class needs to be a subclass of `ContentProvider`.

Here's an example, assuming you already have a provider named `FooBarProvider`:

```
/**
 * Content provider that just adds some logging to {@link FooBarProvider}.
 */
 public class InstrumentedFooBarProvider extends FooBarProvider {
    private static final String TAG = InstrumentedFooBarProvider.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        final Cursor returnValue = super.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        Log.d(TAG, "QUERY on " + uri
                + " with selection " + selection
                + " (" + arrayToString(selectionArgs) + ")."
                + " Result: " + returnValue.getCount());
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        final Uri returnValue = super.insert(uri, values);
        // TODO: analyze values properly
        Log.d(TAG, "INSERT on " + uri
                + " with values " + values + "."
                + " Result: " + returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        final int returnValue = super.update(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);
        // TODO: analyze values properly
        Log.d(TAG, "UPDATE on " + uri
                + " with values " + values
                + " with selection " + selection
                + " (" + arrayToString(selectionArgs) + ")."
                + " Result: " + returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        final int returnValue = super.delete(uri, selection, selectionArgs);
        Log.d(TAG, "Delete operation on " + uri +
                " with " + selection
                + " (" + arrayToString(selectionArgs) + ")."
                + " Result: " + returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public ContentProviderResult[] applyBatch(ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations)
            throws OperationApplicationException {
        final ContentProviderResult[] returnValue = super.applyBatch(operations);
        // TODO: analyze results properly
        Log.d(TAG, "BATCH with " + operations.size() + " operations");
        return returnValue;
    }

    private static Object arrayToString(Object[] array) {
        return array == null ? "[]" : String.valueOf(Arrays.asList(array).toString()); 
    }
}
```

Remember to update the link from the manifest.

Comment: What ContentProvider?

Comment: Well, the content provider that you were querying in the first place. This is specific to Android

Comment: Not all database accesses in Android use a content provider. The one in the question does not.